# WebOS - Web application - screensaver turns on

Tags: webos

Recently I am trying to make a WebOS application for my TV for our application https://castit.nl . It is a web hosted application, therefore all of the logic is on my server.
But the problem is - the application (digital signage that it is) is covered by the screensaver within a few minutes.

There needs to be an API endpoint somewhere - within JavaScript to turn off the screensaver.
I found this article:
https://blog.illixion.com/2022/10/webos-prevent-screensaver/

But this does not work. It is an unsupported API endpoint says the console, and for real because it is not in the documentation:
https://www.webosose.org/docs/reference/webosservicebridge-api/webosservicebridge-api-reference/

Please help as this is really a frustrating thing.

Comment: I am no sure about any API, but screensaver can be disabled in TV settings.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for this for many hours, this seems to be impossible to do.
It does not exist in any API endpoint.